# How to enable picture in picture mode in Samsung Galaxy mobiles?

Tags: settings, 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo

I have enabled the picture in picture mode option in Youtube App settings though unable to utilize the Pic in pic option. Am I missing anything to enable?

Comment: From YouTube's [help center](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7552722?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid), you need 1) YouTube Premium members on Android mobile devices worldwide, or 2) US Android users running Android Oreo or greater, with ad supported PiP playback.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7552722?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

Picture-in-picture is turned on by default for all devices running Android 8.0 (Oreo) and above.
To turn on picture-in-picture:

1. Navigate to your `Android settings > Apps & notifications > Advanced > Special access > Picture-in-picture`.
2. Tap `YouTube`.
3. Toggle `"Allow picture-in-picture”` ON.